# Generating Form for a simple asp.net survey application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]Hi Guys,

I'm working on a simple survey application. I'm faced with the challenge of generating the survey form dynamically from the already existing database question categories.

Basically, I have the questions in 3 major question category with the first category having 2 questions, the second having 3 question and the 3rd also having 3 questions...making 8 questions from 3 major question category.

When I wanted to implement this, the gridView came to mind which eventually I used to generate the form interface. The challenge is, I can't get to format the generated interface the way I need. 
The image of the generated form interface can be accessed also here: 
http://brandberries.com.ng/interface.html

and here is the codeBehind:

```
public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string responder = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
    int catID;
    int qID;
    int canteenID;
    string response;
    string comments;
    string comment;
    string responseDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();

    SqlDataSource sds1 = new SqlDataSource();

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set dataSource properties
        sds1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BNY-D-1245;Initial Catalog=canteenSurvey;Integrated Security=True";
        sds1.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";


        // bind datasource to page
        sds1.DataBind();
        //sds2.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void gvCategory_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvCategory.Rows)
        {
            catID = (int)gvCategory.DataKeys[item.RowIndex].Value;

            GridView gvQuestion = (GridView)item.FindControl("gvQuestion");

            sds1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestion WHERE [CatID] = " + catID;

            gvQuestion.Columns[0].Visible = true;            
            gvQuestion.DataSource = sds1;
            gvQuestion.DataBind();
            gvQuestion.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvQuestion.Rows)
            {
                qID = (int)gvQuestion.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
            }

        }

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow masterItem in gvCategory.Rows)
        {
            catID = (int)gvCategory.DataKeys[masterItem.RowIndex].Value;

            GridView gvQuestion = (GridView)masterItem.FindControl("gvQuestion");

            foreach (GridViewRow masterRow in gvQuestion.Rows)
            {
                qID = (int)gvQuestion.DataKeys[masterRow.RowIndex].Value;

                GridView gvCanteen = (GridView)masterRow.FindControl("gvCanteen");

                foreach (GridViewRow masterData in gvCanteen.Rows)
                {
                    canteenID = (int)gvCanteen.DataKeys[masterData.RowIndex].Value;
                    response = ((DropDownList)masterData.FindControl("ddlResponse")).SelectedValue;
                    //TextBox userComment = gvCanteen.FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox;
                    //comment = userComment.Text;
                }
            }
        }

        comments = txtComments.Text;
        // Insert into the database

        string constr = "Data Source=BNY-D-1245;Initial Catalog=canteenSurvey;Integrated Security=True";

        // SQL Query to insert values into the database

        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tblFeedBack (catID, qID, canteenID, response, responder, responseDate)";
        sqlQuery += "VALUES (@catID, @qID, @canteenID, @response, @responder, @responseDate )";

        //string sqlQuery2 = "INSERT INTO tblComments (responder, comments) VALUES (@responder, @comments)";

        //SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dataConnection.Open();
                dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catID", catID);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qID", qID);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@canteenID", canteenID);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@response", response);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responder", responder);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responseDate", responseDate);

                dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dataConnection.Close();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and here is the aspx file for the survey interface:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Survey.aspx.cs"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Inherits="Survey" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="formStyle">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCategory" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="catID" DataSourceID="CategorySDS" 
            EnableModelValidation="True" onprerender="gvCategory_PreRender" 
            CellPadding="4" CssClass="formStyle" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            Width="100%">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="catID" HeaderText="catID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="catID" Visible="false"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="category" 
                    SortExpression="category" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Questions">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestion" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            DataKeyNames="qID" EnableModelValidation="True" CellPadding="4" 
                            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="qID" HeaderText="qID" ReadOnly="True" 
                                    SortExpression="qID"/>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="question" HeaderText="question" 
                                    SortExpression="question" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Canteen">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvCanteen" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="canteenID" DataSourceID="CanteenSDS" 
                                                EnableModelValidation="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                                                GridLines="None">
                                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="canteenID" HeaderText="canteenID" ReadOnly="True" 
                                                        SortExpression="canteenID" Visible="False" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="canteen" HeaderText="canteen" 
                                                        SortExpression="canteen" />
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Response">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResponse" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                                                                DataSourceID="ResponseSDS" DataTextField="response" 
                                                                DataValueField="responseID" CssClass="formStyle">
                                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">--Select a Response--</asp:ListItem>
                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ResponseSDS" runat="server" 
                                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:canteenSurveyConnectionString %>" 
                                                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblResponse]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                            </asp:GridView>    
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CanteenSDS" runat="server" 
                                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:canteenSurveyConnectionString %>" 
                                                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCanteen]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        </asp:GridView>                        
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    Comments&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Width="50%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CategorySDS" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:canteenSurveyConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </asp:Content>
```

Is there anyways I can format the gridview generated code to look something more organized like the attached?

[image]

I welcome very technique available for use to either improve on the first interface or change the entire interface to the second one without changing my table structure.