# GridView does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'GridView' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got the above error after copying my aspx & cs files to .NET framework 4.0. as the form was originally developed on .NET framework 2.0. Had to copy it over to framework 4.0 because I needed to use chart controls in the project. I ran the page and got the result

> ***Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

```
Source Error:

Line 54: sds1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestion WHERE [CatID] = " + catID;
Line 55: 
Line 56: gvQuestion.Columns[0].Visible = true;            
Line 57: gvQuestion.DataSource = sds1;
Line 58: gvQuestion.DataBind();
```

This is the entire source code to the cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string responder = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
    int catID;
    int qID;
    int canteenID;
    string response;
    string comments;
    string comment;
    string responseDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();

    SqlDataSource sds1 = new SqlDataSource();
    //SqlDataSource sds2 = new SqlDataSource();



    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set dataSource properties
        sds1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BNY-D-1245;Initial Catalog=canteenSurvey;Integrated Security=True";
        sds1.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

        //sds2.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BNY-D-1245;Initial Catalog=canteenSurvey;Integrated Security=True";
        //sds2.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";



        // bind datasource to page
        sds1.DataBind();
        //sds2.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void gvCategory_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvCategory.Rows)
        {
            catID = (int)gvCategory.DataKeys[item.RowIndex].Value;

            GridView gvQuestion = (GridView)item.FindControl("gvQuestion");

            sds1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestion WHERE [CatID] = " + catID;

            gvQuestion.Columns[0].Visible = true;            
            gvQuestion.DataSource = sds1;
            gvQuestion.DataBind();
            gvQuestion.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvQuestion.Rows)
            {
                qID = (int)gvQuestion.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
            }

        }

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow masterItem in gvCategory.Rows)
        {
            catID = (int)gvCategory.DataKeys[masterItem.RowIndex].Value;

            GridView gvQuestion = (GridView)masterItem.FindControl("gvQuestion");

            foreach (GridViewRow masterRow in gvQuestion.Rows)
            {
                qID = (int)gvQuestion.DataKeys[masterRow.RowIndex].Value;

                GridView gvCanteen = (GridView)masterRow.FindControl("gvCanteen");

                foreach (GridViewRow masterData in gvCanteen.Rows)
                {
                    canteenID = (int)gvCanteen.DataKeys[masterData.RowIndex].Value;
                    response = ((DropDownList)masterData.FindControl("ddlResponse")).SelectedValue;

                    comments = txtComments.Text;
                    // Insert into the database

                    string constr = "Data Source=BNY-D-1245;Initial Catalog=canteenSurvey;Integrated Security=True";

                    // SQL Query to insert values into the database

                    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tblFeedBack (catID, qID, canteenID, responseID, responder, responseDate)";
                    sqlQuery += "VALUES (@catID, @qID, @canteenID, @responseID, @responder, @responseDate )";

                    //string sqlQuery2 = "INSERT INTO tblComments (responder, comments) VALUES (@responder, @comments)";

                    //SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
                    using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            dataConnection.Open();
                            dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catID", catID);
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qID", qID);
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@canteenID", canteenID);
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responseID", response);
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responder", responder);
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@responseDate", responseDate);

                            dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            dataConnection.Close();
                        }

                    }



                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm new to asp.net so every help I can get will be appraciated.

Comment: Please build the application

Comment: I have built the application and I'm still getting same error

Comment: can you post your aspx code ?

Comment: Ok Can your please write the aspx code for gridview in detail.

Comment: The both aspx and the cs code are on this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881789/generating-form-for-a-simple-asp-net-survey-application

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error : **CS1061**

> This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class
>   member that does not exist.

Refer : [Compiler Error CS1061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383961.aspx)

So I Can say that you have made some mistake in copy and paste. Instead of copying whole page, you should copy the only grid content of aspx page and same for aspx.cs. Copy only those code which needs to be copied.

For example : In Page attribute you have some wrong values for **CodeFile** or **Inherits**

Comment: I tried your method, I'm still having the same error. I will check my method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `CodeFile` attribute with the `CodeBehind` attribute on your page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Survey.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Inherits="Survey" %>
```